# Issue in Converting BufferedImage to img

Tags: jsp, file-upload, bufferedimage

I am writing code in which i am reading blob image from database and want to show that image on my jsp page .

through google i find out the solution that , byte[] can be converted to buffered image

but how can i use buffered image on jsp page...?

Comment: You don't need `BufferedImage` at all. It serves an entirely different purpose (being able to manipulate (resize, skew, crop, etc) the image). Just write the `byte[]` straight to `response.getOutputStream()` as answered by tusar.

Comment: but i am not using servlet...i am using Spring and Hibernate ...can you tell me how to use response.getOutputStream  in jsp when you we are using Spring controller

Comment: @BalusC : Thanks for giving information on BufferedImage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is to send your image with a servlet or a different jsp.

If you use a JSP, be careful to simply send your binary without any html (or blank line). Like this for example :

```
response.setContentType("image/png");
OutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
BufferedImage myImage = stuff.getImage(request.getParameter("id"));
ImageIO.write(myImage, "png", sos);
sos.flush();
sos.close();
```

(here using javax.imageio.ImageIO)

Then you can simply use the image like this :

```
<img src="myservlet.jsp?id=somestuff">
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend write a servlet `ImageProvider`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>showMyImage</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.photo.gallery.ImageProvider</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>showMyImage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/showMyImage</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now use it in JSP page like :

```
<img src="showMyImage?imageFimeName=flowers.jpg" / >
```

Here goes the `doGet` implementation of `ImageProvider`

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    /*Now you have the byte[] array by some way...
     * Lets call it imageBytes[] */
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    response.setContentLength(imageBytes.length);
    response.getOutputStream().write(imageBytes);
}
```